# Stop TeamCity Build when process exits with code 1

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, mstest

I am creating a TeamCity build configuration with a few steps. One of those steps is running tests using MSTest. Currently, my tests are failing (by design so I can test the build process), but the build steps after the step for running the tests happen, even though I can see the test process exits with code 1 (ie, something other than code 0) in the build log. It does mark the build as failed, but I'd prefer it if the steps in the build stopped once failing tests were detected. Is that possible and I'm just missing something in the configuration?

Answer (score 2):

When you create build step there are select `Execute step` for execution policy. Where you should select `Only if all previous steps were successful`.
Here is it: 
[image]

But in your case there are bug in the MsTest and NUnit build steps. [Here is workaround](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/304572). And [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17002) is related issue.

Comment: I have that option selected (it seems to be the default for all new build steps). The build keeps chugging along, see screenshot of log here: http://i.imgur.com/f7Jtxms.png

Comment: Can you share more configuration details about 3rd step?

Comment: 2nd step is using the MSTest option. 3rd step is using the MSBuild option, with the execute step option set to "Only if all previous steps were successful". Pretty much like your screenshot.

Comment: There is the same problem and workaround http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/304572 And request for fix: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17002 You can vote for this.

Comment: Yea, I had run across that too. Although that powershell script idea looks interesting, I'll have to give that a shot. Hopefully they fix that in an upcoming version...thanks!